# How to create HLS manifest from MPEG DASH segments?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, mp4box, bitmovin-player

Since, Apple has announced the support for fragmented MP4,
Is it possible to create both DASH manifest (.mpd) and HLS manifest (.m3u8) for the same set of segments ( for separate audio and video). How to do it?

Comment: you can see the spec here https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible with ffmpeg, but [shaka-packager](https://github.com/google/shaka-packager/) is able to do just this. Following command will output MP4 segments as well as HLS and DASH manifests, reusing MP4 segments for both (not sure if you can use *existing* MP4 segments though, you might have to mux them back into a single mp4 per video stream first):

```
# HLS + DASH
packager \
    'in=h264_baseline_360p_720.mp4,stream=audio,init_segment=audio_init.mp4,segment_template=audio_$Number$.m4s,playlist_name=audio.m3u8,hls_group_id=audio,hls_name=ENGLISH' \
    'in=h264_baseline_360p_720.mp4,stream=video,init_segment=h264_360p_init.mp4,segment_template=h264_360p_$Number$.m4s,playlist_name=h264_360p.m3u8' \
    'in=h264_main_480p_1400.mp4,stream=video,init_segment=h264_480p_init.mp4,segment_template=h264_480p_$Number$.m4s,playlist_name=h264_480p.m3u8' \
    'in=h264_high_720p_2400.mp4,stream=video,init_segment=h264_720p_init.mp4,segment_template=h264_720p_$Number$.m4s,playlist_name=h264_720p.m3u8' \
    --hls_master_playlist_output h264_master.m3u8 \
    --mpd_output h264.mpd \
    --base_urls https://example.org/ \
    --hls_base_url https://example.org/ \
    --generate_static_mpd
```

Be aware that, at the time of this writing, you need to use the master branch code (or the *google/shaka-packager:latest* docker image), as the newest release *1.6.2* will just exit with *Cannot output both MPD and HLS*.

Although I never used it so far, [Bento4](https://www.bento4.com/) is another tool which is able to [package DASH and HLS](https://github.com/axiomatic-systems/Bento4/issues/80) in a single run:

```
mp4-dash.py  | grep hls
  --hls                 Output HLS playlists in addition to MPEG DASH
  --hls-key-url=<url>   HLS key URL (default: key.bin)
  --hls-master-playlist-name=<filename>
  --hls-media-playlist-name=<filename>
  --hls-iframes-playlist-name=<filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also a experimental GPAC/MP4Box branch on github doing this:

https://github.com/DerouineauNicolas/gpac/tree/m3u8_mpd_rext

So far, expected use is the following:

```
MP4Box -dash 1000 $OUT_DIR/file.mp4#video $OUT_DIR/file.mp4#audio -m3u8-from-mpd $OUT_DIR/hls.m3u8 -segment-name test-$RepresentationID$-$Number%d$ -out $OUT_DIR/file.mpd
```

where -m3u8-from-mpd is the master playlist name. Playlists m3u8 files are generated in the same directory than the master playlist.

Feedbacks are welcome.